# Lighttpd shows no images in html files

Tags: image, browser, configuration, lighttpd, raspberry-pi

I installed Lighttpd, PHP 5 and MySQL on my Raspberry Pi. Everything is working well except the images. If an image is insert in an html file with  Tag, the image is not displayed in the browser. But the image is displayed correctly if you browse to the direct link of the image.

Can this be an misconfiguration of Lighttpd? I can post configuration quotes if required.

thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Probably bad HTML. Do the usual: View the Media of the current page. Flush the cache, reload html only, see `about:cache`, then Disk, look for your image's record. One chance of lighttpd causing it would be the mistyped hotlinking protection where it would have "example.com" not fixed to your actual domain.